# NetworkStream exceptions and return codes

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm trying to educate myself on the intricacies of reading from a NetworkStream, and understanding the various ways in which problems can occur. I have the following code:

```cs
    public async Task ReceiveAll()
    {
        var ns = this.tcp.GetStream();
        var readBuffer = new byte[1000];
        while (true)
        {
            int bytesRead;
            try
            {
                bytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    // Remote disconnection A?
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                // Remote disconnection B?
                break;
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                // Local disconnection?
                break;
            }

            /*Do something with readBuffer */
        }
    }
```

I've marked three points in the code where the program says 'something has gone awry, there is no point continuing'.

The 'Local disconnection' isn't exactly something wrong, it will happen when I locally close the socket which is the only way to exit the loop under normal circumstances. I don't think anything else can cause this, so I think I'm safe to just swallow the exception.

The two 'Remote disconnection' points are what I'm not sure about. I know ReadAsync will return 0 if the connection is terminated remotely (A), but the IOException also seems to fire in some circumstances. If my remote client is a C# console, then closing the socket seems to make 'A' happen, and closing the console window seems to be make 'B' happen. I'm not sure I understand what the difference is between these scenarios?

Finally, a bit of a general question, but is there anything glaringly wrong with this bit of code or my above assumptions?

Thanks.

EDIT: In response to my use of ObjectDisposedException to abort out of the loop:

This is what my 'Stop' method looks like (from the same class as above):

```
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.tcp.Close();
    }
```

This causes the pending 'ReadAsync' to except with ObjectDisposedException. AFAIK there isn't any other way to abort this. Changing this to:

```
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.tcp.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    }
```

Doesn't appear to actually do anything to the pending call, it just continues waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `NetworkStream` returns 0, this means that the socket has received a disconnect packet from the remote party. This is how network connections are supposed to end.

The correct way to shut down the connection (especially if you are in a full-duplex conversation) is to call `socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` and give the remote party some time to close their send channel. This ensures that you receive any pending data instead of slamming the connection shut. `ObjectDisposedException` should never be part of the normal application flow.

Any exceptions thrown indicate that something went wrong, and I think it's safe to say you can no longer rely on the current connection.

**TL;DR**

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but (especially in full-duplex communication) I'd shut down the send channel and wait for a 0-byte packet to prevent receiving `ObjectDisposedException`s by default:

1. use `tcp.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` to tell the remote party you want to disconnect
2. your loop may still receive data that the remote party was sending
3. your loop will, if everything went right, then receive a 0-byte packet, indicating that the remote party is disconnecting
4. loop terminates the right way
5. you may want to decide to dispose the socket after a certain amount of time, if you haven't received the 0-byte packet

Comment: Thanks. The ObjectDisposedException handler is only there as I don't think there is any other way to 'cancel' a ReadAsync when this loop is running without disposing the socket. If 'Remote Disconnection A' is because the remote client 'cleanly' shutdown, then what specifically causes B - i.e. how the local client know the remote client has gone away?

Comment: Responding to your edit: "I'd use the two-step shutdown thing to prevent receiving ObjectDisposedExceptions by default.". Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Barguast: you can prevent `ObjectDisposedException` if you `Shutdown()` on read = 0.

Comment: @Barguast situation B happens when a detectable problem has occurred or the remote party has not responded for a period of time configured in the OS

Comment: @jgauffin I think that problem occurred when the local side wants to shut down

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Same there. Use `Shutdown()` instead of `Close()`. The read will then get a 0 too. `ObjectDisposedException` is only possible if the dev do not wait for a graceful shutdown.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm explained myself properly. The above is 'server code' and comes after a remote connection has been made and the server needs to process any data that gets sent. The server can be stopped by the user, at which point I need to tell these loops (and their pending ReadAsync-s) to stop. I don't think there is anything I can do on the **server** to do this other than dispose the socket?

Comment: @Barguast: Why do you think that you can't use `Shutdown()` in the server side and then wait for the `Read()` to receive 0 bytes read?

Comment: @jgauffin - I've updated my answer to elaborate, but basically it doesn't appear to do anything if I call 'tcp.Client.Shutdown' while ReadAsync is pending.

Comment: @Barguast because you're also shutting down the `Receive` channel. Use `SocketShutdown.Send` to be able to receive the "disconnect acknowledge".

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - Changing the Stop method to call 'this.tcp.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);' also doesn't seem to cause the ReadAsync to return (or except) either

Comment: "I need to tell these loops (and their pending ReadAsync-s) to stop" -- if your clients are well-behaved, then when you call `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`, they will see the 0-byte receive on their end, and once they are done sending anything, they will call `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)` (or their platform's equivalent), and your server will _then_ see a 0-byte receive completion. You may optionally start a timer and then close the socket if you feel the client hasn't responded in a timely manner (i.e. is not well-behaved). But that's not the normal scenario, even if it has to be supported

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I certainly can't rely on the clients being well-behaved. My real-world scenario is various types of mobile equipment connected to my server over GPRS, so all bets are off in regards to connectivity and behaviour.

Comment: @Barguast I find it hard to determine what information you still feel is missing. The well-behaved scenario is repeated a few times, and we also covered the possibility for clients to not behave well. It is up to you to decide to slam the connection shut or give each client some time to close the connection properly.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - I got the impression that jgauffin was telling me that if I do a Socket.Shutdown on the server (i.e. during stop, instead of calling Close) then the ReadAsync will exit by returning 0 immediately, rather than throwing an ObjectDisposedException like Close does. That doesn't seem to be the case. I don't have a problem with calling Close and shallowing the exception assuming there aren't any side effects, but your original answer indicated this is a bad way of doing it.

Comment: @Barguast After `Socket.Shutdown(Send)` a 0-byte packet is sent to the remote party, and when the remote party responds properly, you'll read 0 - so this definitely isn't immediate. When slamming the connection shut using `Socket.Close()` you may miss the last incoming message if it was being sent at the time you were closing the connection.

Comment: OK, I think in this case I have to accept that clients won't be behaving predictably (see my comment a little further up). Thanks for taking the time to go through this with me.

Comment: @Barguast: that's fine, but you still should give them the benefit of the doubt first. Even if some clients won't behave well, you need to start with the assumption that they will so that your code is correct. Use `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` to indicate to the remote endpoint you're done sending, and then don't close the socket until your receive _does_ complete, with a 0-byte length. You may _also_ add to that a timer, which you use to determine when to close the socket, _if and only if_ the remote endpoint does not shutdown in a timely way.